# Connecting to database within ssh'ed application

Tags: java, intellij-idea, ssh, systemd

I've setup a `systemd-nspawn` container with my development environment. I start `Intellij Idea` within this container via:

```
ssh -Y user@development idea.sh
```

Now, when I try to connect the database console to my database server, running in a Windows VM, I get a timeout and the connection fails. Testing if the server is reachable with `netcat` works fine. The container, the Windows VM and the host are connected to a network bridge, each with it's own IP.

**So: What must be done to successfully connect `Intellij Idea` via `JDBC` to my database server in this setup?**

So far, I've tried a port forwarding `ssh -Y -L1234:database:1234 user@development idea.sh` with no success.

Answer (score 0):

You must choose **remote port forwarding** `-R` instead of *local port forwarding* `-L`. The correct shell command would be:

```
ssh -Y -R1234:database:1234 user@development idea.sh
```